# How to ignore any subfolder in the finder component?

Tags: php, symfony

Assume a file structure:

```
config
    └── folder
        └── subfolder
```

I want to iterate over the files using the [finder component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html) of only the content folder using the symfony finder component but not any subfolder.

Currently, the only way I found to exclude the subfolder is a hardcoded:

```
foreach($fileFinder->in($portalConfigPath)->files()->exclude('subfolder') as $file) {...}
```

How to exclude any new subfolder that may be added in the future? I tried `'*'` as a wildcard, yet it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the [depth to 0](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html#directory-depth) to not traverse to subfolders:

```
foreach ($fileFinder->in($portalConfigPath)->files()->depth('== 0') as $file) {...}
```

Comment: That's what I get for not reading the docs to the very end m)

Comment: So did that work for you?  I notice you rarely accept answers to questions but accepting answers helps others know what the proper solutions are if they are encountering the same issue.

Comment: Worked, and I am highely confident that most of my questions have accepted answers. In fact, I tried to upvote and accept yours at once, yet there was a time restriction in place :)

Comment: Okay thanks, I just checked real quick at http://stackoverflow.com/users/457268/k0pernikus and your previous 13 questions did not have an accepted answer so I figured I'd let you know.